# Django get values for Max of grouped data

Tags: python, django, django-models

After many trials and errors and checking similar questions, I think it worth asking it with all the details.

Here's a simple model. Let's say we have a Book model and a Reserve model that holds reservation data for each Book.

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        'Book Title',
        max_length=50
    )

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=250
    )


class Reserve(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        Book,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    reserve_date = models.DateTimeField()

    status = models.CharField(
        'Reservation Status',
        max_length=5,
        choices=[
            ('R', 'Reserved'),
            ('F', 'Free')
        ]
    )
```

I added a book and two reservation records to the model:

```py
from django.utils import timezone

book_inst = Book(title='Book1')
book_inst.save()

reserve_inst = Reserve(book=book_inst, reserve_date=timezone.now(), status='R')
reserve_inst.save()

reserve_inst = Reserve(book=book_inst, reserve_date=timezone.now(), status='F')
reserve_inst.save()
```

My goal is to get data for the last reservation for each book. Based on other questions, I get it to this point:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Q, Max


reserve_qs = Reserve.objects.values(
    'book__title'
)
```

`reserve_qs` now has the last action for each Book, but when I add `.value()` it ignores the grouping and returns all the records.

I also tried filtering with F:

```py
Reserve.objects.values(
    'book__title'
).annotate(
    last_action=Max('reserve_date')
).values(

).filter(
    reserve_date=F('last_action')
)
```

I'm using Django 3 and SQLite.

Comment: Well because you filter on `reserve_date`, it will remove the `GROUP BY`, and hence each item has one record, and that record is the maximum of its "group".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's exactly what I'm looking for. I want to get last record for each book, but after adding .values() to get details for each book, It returns all the records, not just the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using another filter, you will break the `GROUP BY` mechanism. You can however simply obtain the last reservation with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max

Reserve.objects.filter(
    book__title='Book1'
).annotate(
    book_title=F('book__title'),
    last_action=Max('book__reserve__reserve_date')
).filter(
    reserve_date=F('last_action')
)
```

or for all books:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max

qs = Reserve.objects.annotate(
    book_title=F('book__title'),
    last_action=Max('book__reserve__reserve_date')
).filter(
    reserve_date=F('last_action')
).select_related('book')
```

Here we will thus calculate the maximum for that book. Since we here join on the same table, we thus group correctly.

This will retrieve all the last reservations for all `Book`s that are retained after filtering. Normally that is one per `Book`. But if there are multiple `Book`s with multiple `Reservation`s with exactly the same timestamp, then multiple ones will be returned.

So we can for example print the reservations with:

```
for q in qs:
    print(
        'Last reservation for {} is {} with status {}',
        q.book.title,
        q.reserve_date,
        q.status
    )
```

For a single book however, it is better to simply fetch the `Book` object and return the [**`.latest(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) reseervation:

```
Book.objects.get(title='Book1').reserve_set.latest('reserve_date')
```

Comment: Can I somehow get the book_title or book_name from this QS? for example, qs.book_title?  My usecase has many other fields and I need to access those field through this QS

Comment: @MehdiZare: well I here added `book_title` in the `.annotate(..)`, so yes. But note that this is a *queryset*, so `qs.book_title` makes no sense, since it is a *collection* of objects, not a single object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a mistake by adding filter to the QS in first place. Let's say how we can generate a QS with last status for all books.

Comment: @MehdiZare: by removing the `.filter(..)` at the top.

Comment: I did, so now how should I change the code to get last status for each book and have access to book details (name, title)?

Comment: @MehdiZare: this is a collection of `Reserve` objects, so you can *iterate* over it, and for each `Reserve` in the collection access `reserve.book` to obtain the related `Book` object.

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question on `last_action=Max('book__reserve__reserve_date')`, Why `last_action=Max('reserve_date')` doesn't work?

Comment: @MehdiZare: because you can not both aggregate, and return records. If you aggregate, that is a "fold" of the group (or entire record set if there is no group).

Answer (score 0):

```
book_obj = Book.objects.get(title='Book1')
reserve_qs = book_obj.reserve_set.all()
```

This returns all the Reserves that contains this book.
You can get the latest object using `.first` or `.last()` or sort them.

Comment: I'm looking for a qs with fields available in the model, (title, name).